# XML - Checking presence of external references

Tags: xml

I have a database with XML documents, I would like to know what is the fastest way to check for each XML file if the XML files referenced in this file are present in the database ?

Example :
`<xml>
<ref>document.xml</ref>
</xml>`

Thanks for your responses !

Answer (score 0):

you could use `document()` function - if this is empty - no file ?

I am thinking about xslt

Comment: Is XSLT able to call a document in a database ?
My XML files are stored in a database...

Comment: Yes - some XSLT processors are able to access database - [The Saxon SQL Extension](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/sql-extension.html) through extension functions, or with some [workarounds](http://www.braintrove.com/article/30)